# α is a plane curve iff the binormal vector is constant

Tags: differential-geometry, frenet-frame

I've just started studing Differencial Geometry at college and I came across the following exercise

"α is a plane curve iff the binormal vector is constant"

Would you have any hints for this proof?

I know that if the binormal vector is constant then the curve is in the span generated by T(s) and N(s)

Comment: Search this site. You will find a dozen posts on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result you quoted gets one direction, ie if the curve lies in the span of two vectors then it's a plane curve.  For the other direction, assuming $\alpha$ is a plane curve then you can use the definition of binormal vector to show that it must be constant.

Answer (score 0):

For a being planar T,N lie in the same plane making binormal(B) constant.
For the converse suppose B is constant consider function f(s)=(a(s)-a(0)).B which is a zero function then a lies in the plane perpendicular to B.